# Logging function parameters in MATLAB

Tags: logging, matlab

I'm trying to write a generalised logging function for all the input parameters passed to a function in MATLAB. Is it possible to easily pass all the input parameters to another function without individually naming the parameters? In the logging function, I can of course use `inputname(i)` in a for loop to get the parameter names. I would prefer not to have to perform this logic in the main function. So, is there a way to do something like `LogParams(allInputParams)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have a main function, and from that function you want to call a function `LogParams` to get a list of the names of the variables passed to the main function. Here's one way you could implement your function `LogParams`:

```
function names = LogParams
  names = evalin('caller','arrayfun(@inputname,1:nargin,''UniformOutput'',0)');
end
```

The output returned from `LogParams` will be a cell array containing the names of the variables passed to the function that calls `LogParams`. The above solution uses the following functions:

- [EVALIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/evalin.html): to evaluate an expression in the workspace of the calling function.
- [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html): as an alternative to a for loop.
- [NARGIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nargin.html): to get the number of arguments passed to a function.
- [INPUTNAME](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/inputname.html): to get the name of an input variable.

As an illustration of how `LogParams` works, create the following function that calls it:

```
function main_function(a,b,varargin)
  disp(LogParams);
end
```

and now call it with a number of inputs (assuming the variables `x`, `y`, and `z` are defined in the workspace):

```
>> main_function(x,y)
    'x'    'y'

>> main_function(x,y,z)
    'x'    'y'    'z'

>> main_function(x,y,z,z,z,z)
    'x'    'y'    'z'    'z'    'z'    'z'
```